# Is it possible to merge 2 seurat objects from one sample based on their barcodes?

Tags: r, merge, seurat

I separated my seurat object into 2 objects based on some genes,and analyzed them,now I want to merge them again based on their original cells,but when I merge them,the barcodes are changed and I have 2 barcodes of one cell with different indexes.

object1@meta.data:

```
                        orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA
AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1 SeuratProject        181           71
AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1 SeuratProject        153           70
AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1 SeuratProject        171           69
ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1 SeuratProject         70           41
AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1 SeuratProject        224           85
AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1 SeuratProject        758          192
```

object2@meta.data

```
                     orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA 
AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1   alive_14        231          158  
AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1   alive_14        245          148  
AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1   alive_14        275          179  
ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1   alive_14        344          193  
AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1   alive_14        355          194  
AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1   alive_14        397          245
```

The result that I'm looking for :

```
                     orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA 
AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1   alive_14        412          229         
AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1   alive_14        398          218         
AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1   alive_14        446          248        
ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1   alive_14        414          234         
AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1   alive_14        579          279         
AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1   alive_14       1155          437
```

BUT the result I got from merging data is :
merge(object1,object2)

```
                       orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA 
AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1_1   alive_14        231          158  
AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1_1   alive_14        245          148  
AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1_1   alive_14        275          179  
ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1_1   alive_14        344          193  
AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1_1   alive_14        355          194  
AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1_1   alive_14        397          245
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tidyverse`-approach:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(rownames_to_column(object1), rownames_to_column(object2)) %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  summarise(nCount_RNA = sum(nCount_RNA),
            nFeature_RNA = sum(nFeature_RNA)) %>% 
  mutate(orig.ident = "alive_14", .before = 2)
```

gives you

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  rowname              orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA
  <chr>                <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>
1 AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1 alive_14          412          229
2 AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1 alive_14          398          218
3 AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1 alive_14          446          248
4 ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1 alive_14          414          234
5 AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1 alive_14          579          279
6 AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1 alive_14         1155          437
```

### Data

```r
object1 <- structure(list(orig.ident = c("SeuratProject", "SeuratProject", 
"SeuratProject", "SeuratProject", "SeuratProject", "SeuratProject"
), nCount_RNA = c(181, 153, 171, 70, 224, 758), nFeature_RNA = c(71, 
70, 69, 41, 85, 192)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1", 
"AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1", "AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1", "ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1", 
"AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1", "AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), orig.ident = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), nCount_RNA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), nFeature_RNA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

```r
object2 <- structure(list(orig.ident = c("alive_14", "alive_14", "alive_14", 
"alive_14", "alive_14", "alive_14"), nCount_RNA = c(231, 245, 
275, 344, 355, 397), nFeature_RNA = c(158, 148, 179, 193, 194, 
245)), problems = structure(list(row = 1:5, col = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    expected = c("4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
    "4 columns"), actual = c("5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
    "5 columns", "5 columns"), file = c("literal data", "literal data", 
    "literal data", "literal data", "literal data")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AAAGTCCTCCCTGGTT_1_1", 
"AACACACTCTAGATCG_1_1", "AATAGAGGTGACGCCT_1_1", "ACTCCCAAGAGGCTGT_1_1", 
"AGATCCAAGGGCGAAG_1_1", "AGGTCATCAGAACTCT_1_1"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), orig.ident = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), nCount_RNA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), nFeature_RNA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is what do you need to keep with the Seurat object between the two different datasets? For the data slots (seurat[[assay]]@counts) you can probably just row bind the two matrices together using rbind. (Just be cautious merging the normalized values and if that would violate any assumptions).

Next for Dimension Reductions and Graphs, you can put them into a slot by pulling the Dimension Reduction or graph from one object into a new Seurat object.

Here's some pseudocode to help (I use V3, but if you use V2, just change the slot names)

```
merge_data <- rbind(object1[[assay]]@counts, object2[[assay]]@counts)
# repeat for other slots/assays (maybe write a function?)

metadata <- rbind(object1[[]], object2[[]])

seurat_merge <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = merge_data, meta.data = metadata)

# Place dim_reds
seurat_merge[["UMAP_object1"]] <- object1[["UMAP"]]
# repeat for more reductions (maybe write a function?)
```

An easier solution might just be to reimport the data as any dimension reductions aren't comparable between the two datasets unless you project one dataset onto another. You can then just add any relevant metadata from the two analyses into the freshly imported object.